# Phonegap blackberry photo upload server php script

Tags: php, html, cordova, blackberry, camera

There are many people asking questions related to this issue, but none are complete enough for me to solve my issue.

I have created a fully working HTML5 smartphone app, based on phonegap, for.. shudder... Blackberry that is sending data nicely to a remote MYSQL server using a server side php script.

However I want to give the option to also upload a photo as this is injury prevention, and hazards need photographing. This is a NON commercial product, it is a working example of modern smartphone technologies and to demonstrate how one app can be ported easily to various smartphones.. Blackberry is the common phone and has to be the prime example.

I cannot for love nor money find any working examples of an app and a php server side script together.

The example I have extracted from the CORDOVA example file takes a picture, and I can see the generated thumbnail in my app, and that bit is all sweet (based on all code you see below), but I dont know what I need to program for my upload.php to do something. Everything I try just fails with error code 3 and 1..

Here is the important code for the webapp.

HTML

```
    <h3>navigator.camera</h3>
<input type="button" value="Get Photo (Data)" onclick="capturePhoto();return false;" /> 
<input type="button" value="Get Photo (URI)" onclick="capturePhotoURI();return false;" /> 
<img style="display:none;width:120px;height:120px;" id="cameraImage" src="" />
<p id="uploadProgress"></p>
<input style="display:none;" id="uploadButton" type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadImage();return false;" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
        function capturePhotoURI() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhotoURISuccess, fail, 
            { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, quality: 50 });
    }

        function onCapturePhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        if (imageURI != null) {
            var smallImage = document.getElementById('cameraImage');
            var uploadButton = document.getElementById('uploadButton');

            // Unhide image elements
            smallImage.style.display = 'block';
            uploadButton.style.display = 'block';

            // Show the captured photo
            // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
            smallImage.src = imageURI;
        }
    }

        function uploadImage() {
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('cameraImage');
        if (smallImage.src && smallImage.src !== "") {
            var f = new FileTransfer();
            f.upload(
                // file path
                smallImage.src,
                // server URL - update to your own, and don't forget to 
                // include your domain in an access element in config.xml      
                "http://192.168.1.91/upload.php",
                // success callback
                function(result) {
                    document.getElementById('uploadProgress').innerHTML =
                        result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent';
                    alert(result.responseCode + ": " + result.response);
                },
                // error callback
                function(error) {
                    alert('error uploading file: ' + error.code);
                },
                // options
                { fileName: 'myImage.jpg', 
                  params: { 'username':'jtyberg' } 
                });
        }
    }
```

The server Id above is correct (it is the proper translation of my own development server so I am not using localhost, as I need this to be accurate). Everything you see with the exception of the server IP is vanilla, out the box, unaltered working example from phonegap. The phone is one the same 192 network and defintaly tries to run whatever upload.php I try

Basically I want to take this file, and using the upload.php file move it to

http : // 192.168.1.91/injury/sample_images/xxxx.jpg (spacing http as not sure how to stop it linking)

I have checked rights they are all ok, and my config.html has allow all domains

can anyone please put me out my misery and give me an example upload.php that will use the upload code above and just do something with the camera image.

Once I can get a working example, I can break down exactly what is happening and start the learning process.

Alternativly if someone can provide a working app.. with both app and server side code to use as a tutorial, I am happy to do the studying involved.

Many many thanks in advance for any time people give to this. I am at my wits end, and getting myself in a right muddle when I should be able to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a posting method of the base64 string. I did find however that in this case it was more likely to be the settings on my development server that were the likely cause.

Comment: can i see your posting method?